# Find Tuple item in list

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I am saving multiple tuples that contain strings in a list:
`List<Tuple<string, string, string>> ExcelRawImport`

What i want to do now, is find the tuple in the list, where the `Tuple.Item1` has an specific value.

how should i do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Linq I would say

```
var specificValue = "mySpecificValue";

var foundTuple = ExcelRawImport.FirstOrDefault(eri => eri.Item1 == specificValue);
```

This returns the first Item from your list that matches the specific value. If no matching value is found, foundTuple is null.

If you need all items that match you can use the Where() statement instead.

```
var foundTuples = ExcelRawImport.Where(eri => eri.Item1 == specificValue).ToList();
```